# Is there any benefits of using fewer SQL database tables for similar types of content?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I usually add standalone photos, photos associated with **photo albums**, standalone downloadable files for and media files associated to **media albums** to the database using different ASP.NET to insert to and update database tables as follow:

```
  -Articles
   --Pictures
   --Downloads
   --PhotoAlbums
   ---Photos
   --MediaAlbums
   ---MediaFiles
```

What I'm trying to understand is what benefits may I get if merged all these tables in one using something like "Type" or "TypeID" (for example like WordPress posts)? of course I know I will have to change my codes but need to know does it make any difference when I have few or many database tables and if this (after doing the code changes) will reflect on how the code is more organized and easier to handle?

## Note:

For sure I currently use different asp.net page to add, edit and list each of the above.

Comment: There are very likely pros and cons to either choice, all of which are highly dependent on your particular needs.  Try one and come back with _specific_ questions or concerns.  In general, there's not a huge benefit to having fewer tables.

Comment: Some things to consider, though...  How many attributes are common to all types?  Would it ever make sense to change an item from one type to another?  Does your app treat each type differently in all respects? Do you often list items of all (or several types) together?

Comment: these questions may really help. In general most of them point to the merge technique. Thank you @DStanley

Comment: The major benefit to a normalized schema is that you can expand the number of "types" by simply adding records to a table.